# How and Why other should buy and sell my ICO token?

Tags: tokens, ether, ico, bitcoin

When I invest or create a token, I am hoping someone in the future will want to buy it at a higher price. Why would anyone buy my tokens to use the platform if the price of the token keeps increasing as I expect it to?

Comment: Why do you expect the price of your token to keep increasing? (I'm assuming you mean _after_ the crowdsale phase, when your token is available on the open market.)

Comment: Exactly. I want to ICO Token selling and buying criteria. What price of first token? Who will buy my token? or How can i make others to buy my token? How price define in ICO token in first time? which basis token value up and down?

Comment: During the crowdsale phase you can set the price of the token to any value you like. Have a look at OpenZeppelin's crowdsale contracts for some ideas:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale

Comment: Once the crowdsale has ended, and users are able to freely trade your tokens on the open market, then the price will be set by supply and demand. Unless you can control the token supply in some way, you won't have any control over the price set by the market. If the market doesn't like your token, it will be worth nothing.